# How do I get the API name of a profile?

Tags: visualforce, profile

I am trying to expand a single select dropdown on a Visualforce page to include an additional sales profile. However, when I copy the code I receive an error that Variable does not exist. Here is the code I am working with:

```
public List<SelectOption> activePartnerPortalUsers {
    get {
        if (activePartnerPortalUsers == null) {
            activePartnerPortalUsers = new List<SelectOption>();
            activePartnerPortalUsers.add( new SelectOption('' , 'Please select a specialist' ));

            Profile pdtProfile = [
                SELECT p.Name , p.Id
                FROM Profile p
                WHERE p.Name LIKE :PROFESSIONAL_DEVELOPMENT_TRAINER
                LIMIT 1
            ];

            Profile pdAdminProfile = [
                SELECT p.Name , p.Id
                FROM Profile p
                WHERE p.Name LIKE :PROFESSIONAL_DEVELOPMENT_ADMIN
                LIMIT 1
            ];

             Profile salesProfile = [
                SELECT p.Name , p.Id
                FROM Profile p
                WHERE p.Name LIKE :sales
                LIMIT 1
            ];

            if (pdtProfile != null) {
                for (User user : [
                    SELECT u.Name , u.LastName, u.Id
                    FROM User u
                    WHERE u.IsActive = true
                        AND (
                            u.ProfileId = : pdtProfile.Id
                            OR
                            u.ProfileId = : pdAdminProfile.Id
                            OR
                            u.ProfileID = :salesProfile.Id 
                            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different reasons this error may be occurring for you. What caught my attention first was the `sales` variable (shown on line 4 below). You should make sure that is defined somewhere else in your code.

```
1    Profile salesProfile = [
2        SELECT p.Name , p.Id
3        FROM Profile p
4        WHERE p.Name LIKE :sales
5        LIMIT 1
6    ];
```

That variable doesn't appear to be included in the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you, your post made me realize that sales was not define. I then search for PROFESSIONAL_DEVELOPMENT_ADMIN to see how that profile had been defined. I then defined the sales variable in a similar way:                      >private final string PROFESSIONAL_DEVELOPMENT_TRAINER = 'Professional Development Trainer' ; private final string PROFESSIONAL_DEVELOPMENT_ADMIN = 'Professional Development Admin' ; private final string Sales_Teams = 'Sales Teams';

Comment: Note that you could avoid multiple SOQL queries by dropping the queries to get the profiles and update the last query: SELECT u.Name , u.LastName, u.Id
                    FROM User u
                    WHERE u.IsActive = true
                        AND u.Profile.Name in ('Professional Development Trainer', 'Professional Development Admin', 'Sales Teams')

Comment: Thumbs up, thanks @DanielHoechst . Always looking to make things cleaner :)

Comment: I made the appropriate edits in the code as indicated above. The code works great in my sandbox, when I deploy to the config sandbox  I get the following error: action="{!resendEvent}": Unknown method 'Professional_Development_Event__cStandardController.resendEvent()' Any idea why this may be happening? @Matthew Keefe

Comment: Sorry I'm not entirely sure; need more info. It would be best post your updated code and error message in a new question; that would help get you an answer most quickly.